# WebServiceTransportException Temporary Redirect 307

Tags: java, soap, redirect, spring-ws, http-status-code-307

I wrote soap client service using Java.
Also I used Spring WS.
When I send request via SoapUI I get response.
When I send request using client code, I get error

```
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Temporary Redirect [307]

    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleError(WebServiceTemplate.java:699)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:609)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:383)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:373)
```

Client Config

```
class SushiClientConfig {

    private Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller(String pathToGeneratedClasses) {
        Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        jaxb2Marshaller.setContextPath(pathToGeneratedClasses);
        return jaxb2Marshaller;
    }

    WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate(String pathToGeneratedClasses, String uri) {
        WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
        webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller(pathToGeneratedClasses));
        webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller(pathToGeneratedClasses));
        webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri(uri);
        webServiceTemplate.setMessageSender(webServiceMessageSender());
        return webServiceTemplate;
    }

    private WebServiceMessageSender webServiceMessageSender() {
        HttpComponentsMessageSender httpComponentsMessageSender = new HttpComponentsMessageSender();
        httpComponentsMessageSender.setReadTimeout(SushiConstants.TIMEOUT);

        return httpComponentsMessageSender;
    }
}
```

**Can you help me?
I really don't know how to fix it. Thanks!**

Comment: Do we have a chance to redirect request on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of investigation, I decided to get just redirected URLs.
So issue is not resolved for SPRING-WS